# Display Flask Data using React Proxy

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

This is my first go at using react and flask. I am trying to display the time from a flask endpoint using react. I am getting a 200 status on the flask server, but a bad request on the browser. It does not contain a response code but is in red with no response information.

Flask is on port 5000 and react is on 3000. I added a proxy to my package.json file in the form of "proxy":"http:localhost:5000/".

The website says the current time is 0 which is wrong, I dont think react is receiving the flask data somehow. The flask side is printing out the time and I see it on the server side giving a 200 code.

the flask app (app.py) is contained in the main directory along with the react app (canoe-finder).

Im very new to react. So any help is welcomed.

React Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/time').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      setCurrentTime(data.time);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

        ... no changes in this part ...

        <p>The current time is {currentTime}.</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when i use fetch('/time')instead of fetch('http://localhost:5000/time') I get this error

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /time from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000:.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

Flask Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, jsonify, flash
import sqlite3
import time
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

app = Flask(__name__)




@app.route('/time')
def get_current_time():
    print(time.time())
    return jsonify('time', time.time())
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the correct syntax for your Flask server running on the localhost will be `http://localhost:5000`. Secondly, when you `fetch('/time')` in development, the development server will recognize that it’s not a static asset and will proxy your request to `http://localhost:5000/time` as a fallback.

You can read more about this [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) if you are interested.

Also when fetching data in useEffect you should have some sort of loading state variable.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/time').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      setCurrentTime(data.time);
    });
    setLoading(false)
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading data...</h1>
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>The current time is {currentTime}.</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Oh, also if you are new to web development and React I highly recommend you to use the developer console in, for example, Google chrome. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open

You'll get errors as well as inspect and analyze the requests you are sending in the "Network" tab.

Comment: great thank you, when i double click on the request I see the data from flask. Its just not populating on the screen

Comment: I get this error when I simply use fetch("/time") --- Proxy error: Could not proxy request /time from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000:."

Comment: how do you start your react development server?

Comment: I use yarn start. I also added my flask python script insdie the react app. still no luck

Comment: have you tried with http://0.0.0.0:5000 or http://127.0.0.1:5000 as well?

Comment: I ended up getting it to work. I re arranged by directory and added the flask environment variables using dotenv